# Using lambda expression inside a loop is giving me an error,how do I resolve this?

Tags: java, list, loops, arraylist, methods

```
    while(flag==false){
        loc=Collections.min(sticks);
        result[k++]=sticks.size();
        sticks.removeIf(f -> (f==loc));
        sticks.replaceAll(g ->(g-loc));        
    }
```

Solution.java:24: error: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final

```
             sticks.removeIf(f -> (f==loc));
```

Solution.java:25: error: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final

```
            sticks.replaceAll(g ->(g-loc));
```

Comment: Define loc inside the loop.

Comment: Your [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/62017752/3) just completely changed the error message.

Comment: what is the type of loc variable?

Comment: loc is an integer which was initialised as 0.

Comment: @AndyTurner I posted the wrong error by mistake.

Comment: What is the data type of sticks?

Comment: You should not write expressions like `flag==false`; the idiomatic form is `! flag`. But anyway, since `flag` is never changed in this loop, but you are repeatedly removing from a collection that doesn’t have infinite capacity, this loop condition looks like an error waiting to happen. If this code is supposed to run until the list is empty, the `sticks.replaceAll(g ->(g-loc));` is entirely obsolete. Even when you intend to exit the loop with a non-empty collection, performing `sticks.replaceAll(g -> g-loc);` once at the end with the last `loc` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure the 'loc' variable never changes after declaration.

This will work:

```
  while(flag==false){
    int loc=Collections.min(sticks);
    result[k++]=sticks.size();
    sticks.removeIf(f -> (f==loc));
    sticks.replaceAll(g ->(g-loc));        
  }
```

This won't:

```
  int loc = -1;
  while(flag==false){
    loc=Collections.min(sticks);
    result[k++]=sticks.size();
    sticks.removeIf(f -> (f==loc));
    sticks.replaceAll(g ->(g-loc));        
  }
```

The compiler doesn't know when the lambda will be executed, so it needs to be able to know at compile time how to resolve all variables.

In the first case, the loc variable is only assigned once, so the compiler can use that to link. In the second case, the same loc variable is assigned multiple times, so the compiler cannot compile the lambda function.